# indicate if rows exist in joined table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to check, en masse, whether data exists in various tables. I have a main table, A, and various tables that have data relating to A - call them tables B, C, and D. I want to write a single query, that, for each entry in A, indicates if there are any rows in each of B, C, and D.

The first attempt at this was as follows:

```
SELECT A.id, count(B.id) as b_count, count(C.id) as c_count, count(d.id) as d_count
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON B.a_id = A.id
LEFT JOIN C ON C.a_id = A.id
LEFT JOIN D ON D.a_id = A.id
GROUP BY A.id
```

This gives me the correct results - the number of rows in each sub-table, listed by id in the main table. However, this query is also incredibly inefficient, as it involves multiple joins, and I don't really care about how many rows are in each of the sub-tables, just whether there are any rows at all.

Can someone suggest a better alternative?

Comment: how many records are there in each table? and what is the execution time?

Comment: A has 1300 rows. B has 120000, C has 190000 rows, D has 200000 rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont care about how many rows there are on the tables

Use:

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table1 WHERE ...)
```

Refer to MYSQL doc:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for. Ran much faster than the join, and seems not to be bothered by the number of rows involved in the various tables.

Answer (score 0):

Joining is not inefficient, it's the entire thing a relational database management system (RDBMS) like MySQL is optimized for. As long as you have proper indexes on all primary and foreign keys there is no faster way to check for existence of rows in tables other than selecting them.